# How to add photos to photo library in IOS 8 using Photos framework

Tags: ios, photosframework

I was using AlAsset library before, now for more info iam using Photos framework, I am able to get the photos and its info, but how to add to photo album back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create and use `PHAssetChangeRequest` objects within a photo library change block to create, delete, or modify PHAsset objects. [See Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html)

Also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
             NSLog(@"Success");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"write error : %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Check this answer, >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694088/2226263