# PhAsset get fileSize iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, photolibrary

Is there any way to get a file size from PHAsset object apart from the below API

```
 - (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset options:(nullable PHImageRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void(^)(NSData *__nullable imageData, NSString *__nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *__nullable info))resultHandler;
```

We could get the fileSize directy in ALAsset object but i couldnt find it in PHAsset object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately PHAsset doesn't contain such info. Also please note that ALAsset's `fileSize` doesn't work properly if image is in the cloud.
So if you need a stable way of fetching image size from both cloud and local storage just use this:

```
// Fetch image data to retrieve file size and path
PHImageRequestOptions * options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;

options.synchronous = YES; //Set this to NO if is needed

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:photoAsset
                                                  options:options
                                            resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info)
 {
     //(CGFloat)imageData.length returns size in bytes
     NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf MB", ((CGFloat)imageData.length)/1024/1024]);
 }];
```

To gain a little performance set `options.sunchronous = NO;`.
But if you need more performance You can [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset/28900402#28900402) making an `ALAsset` object from `PHAsset` and get `fileSize` from there, but keep in mind that ALAssetLibrary is deprecated and getting file size of image from cloud will not properly work.

Comment: I know about requestImageDataForAsset but it is quite time consuming. Is there any way other than this API

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

Get `file size` in MB from `PHAsset`:

```
extension PHAsset {
    var fileSize: Float {
        get {
            let resource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: self)
            let imageSizeByte = resource.first?.value(forKey: "fileSize") as? Float ?? 0
            let imageSizeMB = imageSizeByte / (1024 * 1024)
            return imageSizeMB
        }
    }
}
```