# URL Scheme to post to Instagram Stories

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api, url-scheme

Is there a way to post a video or photo directly to the Instagram Stories of the user's Instagram account? For a normal photo share on Instagram, you can use the URL Scheme and open the Editor directly. Is there a way for Stories, too?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry there isn't API or Scheme for stories yet. https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

please +1 if it's helpful

Answer (score 13):

Swift 4.2 version of [knshn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653828/3151675):

```
func shareBackgroundImage() {
    let image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "backgroundImage")

    if let pngImage = image.pngData() {
        backgroundImage(pngImage, attributionURL: "http://your-deep-link-url")
    }
}

func backgroundImage(_ backgroundImage: Data, attributionURL: String) {
    // Verify app can open custom URL scheme, open if able

    guard let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) else {
            // Handle older app versions or app not installed case

            return
    }

    let pasteboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": backgroundImage,
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL": attributionURL]]
    let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]

    // This call is iOS 10+, can use 'setItems' depending on what versions you support
    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)

    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
}
```

Comment: Can someone please elaborate what attributionURL: "http://your-deep-link-url" would look like? I'm trying to get the apps App Store page link appear in the top left corner, under the Facebook Story users name.

Comment: @Krekin this was officially a "closed beta" feature and appears to have been removed from the documentation since.

Comment: According to the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/, the new way of attributing appears to be using this url-scheme: "instagram-stories://share?source_application=com.my.app"

Answer (score 7):

Instagram officially supports this since March 2018. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

For iOS:

You need to add `instagram-stories` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your app's `Info.plist`.

This sample code shows how to pass the Instagram app a background layer image asset and an attribution deep link.

```
- (void)shareBackgroundImage {
      [self backgroundImage:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"])
             attributionURL:@"http://your-deep-link-url"];
}

- (void)backgroundImage:(NSData *)backgroundImage 
         attributionURL:(NSString *)attributionURL {

  // Verify app can open custom URL scheme, open if able
  NSURL *urlScheme = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram-stories://share"];
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlScheme]) {

        // Assign background image asset and attribution link URL to pasteboard
        NSArray *pasteboardItems = @[@{@"com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage" : backgroundImage,
                                       @"com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL" : attributionURL}];
        NSDictionary *pasteboardOptions = @{UIPasteboardOptionExpirationDate : [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 5]};
        // This call is iOS 10+, can use 'setItems' depending on what versions you support
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setItems:pasteboardItems options:pasteboardOptions];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlScheme options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
  } else {
      // Handle older app versions or app not installed case
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Hi Is there a way that app can share data on Instagram when Instagram app not installed on device?

Answer (score 1):

**For SwiftUI**

```
import SwiftUI

fileprivate let wands: [Wand] = [
    Wand(name: "Dumbledore's Wand", stickerAsset: "dumbledore"),
    Wand(name: "Potter's Wand", stickerAsset: "potter"),
    Wand(name: "Granger's Wand", stickerAsset: "granger")
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func shareToInstagramStories(
        stickerImage: String,
        stickerLink: String,
        backgroundTopColor: String = "#7F0909",
        backgroundBottomColor: String = "#303030"
    ) {
        // 1. Get a data object of our UIImage...
        let stickerImageData = UIImage(named: stickerImage)?.pngData()
        
        // 2. Verify if we are able to open instagram-stories URL schema.
        // If we are able to, let's add our Sticker image to UIPasteboard.
        
        let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share?source_application=\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "")")
        
        if let urlScheme = urlScheme {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) {
                
                var pasteboardItems: [[String : Any]]? = nil
                if let stickerImageData = stickerImageData {
                    pasteboardItems = [
                        [
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage": stickerImageData,
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundTopColor": backgroundTopColor,
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundBottomColor": backgroundBottomColor,
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.link": stickerLink
                        ]
                    ]
                }
                
                // We'll expire these pasteboard items in 5 minutes...
                let pasteboardOptions = [
                    UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)
                ]
                
                if let pasteboardItems = pasteboardItems {
                    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)
                }
                
                // 3. Try opening the URL...
                UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // App may not be installed. Handle those errors here...
                print("Something went wrong. Maybe Instagram is not installed on this device?")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(wands, id: \.name){ wand in
                Text(wand.name).onTapGesture {
                    shareToInstagramStories(stickerImage: wand.stickerAsset, stickerLink: "www.google.com")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Ollivanders"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct Wand {
    let name: String
    let stickerAsset: String
}
```

Special thanks to [Ishan Chhabra][https://ishanchhabra.com/thoughts/sharing-to-instagram-stories]

Comment: is com.instagram.sharedSticker.link property still working? I've already implemented it but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900402/3943258) to convert a PHAsset's identifier into an asset URL, then format it into an `instagram://` URL using [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks/33558029#33558029). That used to only be capable of making conventional Instagram posts, but as of the past few weeks it actually prompts users if they want to make a story or a post with the asset you provided on launch!

Answer (score 0):

If you download .ipa of instagram and look at their Info.plist, we can found :

```
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>instagram-stories</string>
      <string>fb124024574287414</string>
      <string>instagram</string>
      <string>instagram-capture</string>
      <string>fsq+kylm3gjcbtswk4rambrt4uyzq1dqcoc0n2hyjgcvbcbe54rj+post</string>
    </array>
```

but of course it's private (not official) and not documented by Instagram. If anyone now how to use it/find parameters, I'm really curious to know !