# iPhone X bug when posting on instagram stories

Tags: ios, video, instagram, url-scheme, iphone-x

Following this thread [URL Scheme to post to Instagram Stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283082/url-scheme-to-post-to-instagram-stories) I could post a video directly to Instagram from my iOS app.

The video generated from my app is 1080x1920 (Instagram Stories full-screen size), but for some reason Instagram is transforming the size of it (it makes it wider) **only** on iPhone X. I have tested iPhone 7, 8Plus and SE.

Is anyone having the same problem?

I have tried to report this bug to instagram through their developer site but they only let me report API issues (not iOS issues).

Thanks!

PS: On iPhone X, if I save the video to the camera roll, and manually navigate to instagram, post new story, and select the video, everything works as expected. The problem is only when sending it through URL Scheme.

Comment: Yep, I'm experiencing exact same issue and no idea why.   Did you find a work around?

Comment: No workaround/solution yet... :(

Comment: Good news. I got connected with someone at Instagram and they reproduced the bug. They are fixing it and it’s going out in their app update next week.

Comment: Thank you @TMC , can you answer my question so I can mark it as resolved? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news. I got connected with someone at Instagram and they reproduced the bug. They are fixing it and it’s going out in their app update next week.