# Get file size of PHAsset without loading in the resource?

Tags: swift, image, phasset, photolibrary

Is there a way to get the file size on disk of a `PHAsset` without doing `requestImageDataForAsset` or converting it to `ALAsset`? I am loading in previews of a user's photo library - potentially many thousands of them - and it's imperative to my app that they know the size before import.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can grab the `fileSize` of a PHAsset and convert it to human readable form like this:

```
let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: yourAsset) // your PHAsset
          
var sizeOnDisk: Int64? = 0
        
if let resource = resources.first {
    let unsignedInt64 = resource.value(forKey: "fileSize") as? CLong
    sizeOnDisk = Int64(bitPattern: UInt64(unsignedInt64!))
}
```

Then use your `sizeOnDisk` variable and pass it into a method like this...

```
func converByteToHumanReadable(_ bytes:Int64) -> String {
     let formatter:ByteCountFormatter = ByteCountFormatter()
     formatter.countStyle = .binary
     
     return formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(bytes))
 }
```

Comment: It's not in any documentation because it's accessing the header files. Technically this is a small piece of Apple's private APIs. However, we have submitted a build and received full approval without issue.

Comment: Is it safety to take only first item? As apple said: " An asset can contain multiple resources - for example, an edited photo asset contains resources for both the original and edited images".

Comment: We'll probably need to check the `resources` for the image resources: `kUTTypeJPEG, AVFileType.heic.rawValue, kUTTypePNG, kUTTypeTIFF, kUTTypeRawImage`

Comment: UPD. But I noticed that the `resources.last` is always the most recent resource (iOS 13).

Comment: For iCloud albums video and images, I'm getting zero (0) as size.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 5.0**
Light & Easy:

```
private static let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()

func getSize(asset: PHAsset) -> String {
    let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)

    guard let resource = resources.first,
          let unsignedInt64 = resource.value(forKey: "fileSize") as? CLong else {
              return "Unknown"
          }

    let sizeOnDisk = Int64(bitPattern: UInt64(unsignedInt64))
    Self.bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
    Self.bcf.countStyle = .file
    return Self.bcf.string(fromByteCount: sizeOnDisk)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A safer solution:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput * _Nullable contentEditingInput, NSDictionary * _Nonnull info) {
    NSNumber *fileSize = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL getResourceValue:&fileSize forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:&error];
    NSLog(@"file size: %@\nerror: %@", fileSize, error);
}];
```

Swift version:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil) { (contentEditingInput, _) in
    do {
        let fileSize = try contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL?.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.fileSizeKey]).fileSize
        print("file size: \(String(describing: fileSize))")
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Inspired by [How to get an ALAsset URL from a PHAsset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset)

Comment: This method is so heavy. Won't work for the thousands of assets.

Comment: Yes, so it is better to execute in a background thread and cache the result.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: YourAsset)
var sizeOnDisk: Int64 = 0

if let resource = resources.first {
   let unsignedInt64 = resource.value(forKey: "fileSize") as? CLong
   sizeOnDisk = Int64(bitPattern: UInt64(unsignedInt64!))

   totalSize.text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(sizeOnDisk) / (1024.0*1024.0))+" MB"
}
```