# Saving image with name to Album using Photos framework

Tags: swift, photosframework, phasset

I'm trying to save images to a gallery album using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27660747/2594560.

But I want to store image name too, for uniquely identifying those images. Also, those image will be used at the time of retrieval. I'm new to Photos framework. Please guide me

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This only works on iOS 9 and higher. On iOS 9 use the  `addResourceWithType:fileURL:options:` method of `PHAssetCreationRequest` and set `originalFilename` property of `PHAssetResourceCreationOptions` to a filename of your choice.

Comment: how to get de fileURL ?