# How to access images from custom album

Tags: ios, swift, photo

I want to get all images included in a photo album named "summer" and put all the photos into array in Swift. I've search about it a lot from the internet and all I see is that all the post are about taking photos from camera roll. I don't see any post about taking photos from custom album. How can I do that?

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: I've search about it a lot from the internet and all I see is that all the post are about taking photos from camera roll. I don't see any post about taking photos from custom album.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album