# Swift: Adding Photo To Custom Album

Tags: ios, swift, assets

I'm trying to implement function that saves captured photo to custom album following this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album).

But I encountered error in this line (see [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album) and [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHObjectPlaceholder_Class/index.html)):

```
albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
```

> Contextual type of NSFastEnumeration cannot be used as Array Literal

Comment: Just need to add '!' after `assetPlaceholder`. The error is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because signature of `addAssets` is:

```
func addAssets(_ assets: NSFastEnumeration)
```

What that means is that it expects collection that conforms to `NSFastEnumeration` of which Swift `Array` does not, but `NSArray` does. Thus, creating `NSArray` from your array of `PHObjectPlaceholder` object  works fine.

```
let fastEnumeration = NSArray(array: [photo.placeholderForCreatedAsset!] as [PHObjectPlaceholder])
albumChangeRequest!.addAssets(fastEnumeration)
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work with Swift 3

`albumChangeRequest.addAssets([photoPlaceholder] as NSArray)`