# How to save images into a separate album with an id from previous view controller

Tags: swift, swift3, save-image

I am trying to save an image which is taken from the camera into a separate album each time the image is taken. Now with the code i have written the image is saving but into the shared photo album, it is not saving into the folder i want it to be saved in but does create the folder. Also i want a new folder to be created each time the image is taken with the album name as 'LiQu' but i need it to have an ID number next to the folder which is taken from the previous view controller. 
I have uploaded my attempt at the code.

The view-controller where i am trying create a directory and save the image to.

```swift
import UIKit
import Photos

let albumName = "LiQu"  // "+ID" i want to add the ID number from the previous view controller which is entered by the user
var transferImage: UIImage?

//var redlineX: Double = 0


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var albumFound : Bool = false
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
    var photosAsset: PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.32, green: 0.667, blue: 0.754, alpha: 1)

        //Check if LiQu album exists

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)


        if (collection.firstObject != nil){

        // found the album

        self.albumFound = true
        self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject!

        }else{
            // create the album


            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                //let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
            })

                  }

    }
```

The view-controller from where i am wanting to use the "ID" entered as the name of the directory in the code above.

```swift
import UIKit

class FormViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ID: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var organdonationno: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var donorage: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var snodname: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var donorshospital: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var date: UITextField!
```

I hope this makes sense and any help given is greatly appreciated, i am a newbie at this so please bear with me if i have made any mistakes.

ThankYou

Comment: @luckyShubhra this is my question. If you could help would be great! Thank-You

Comment: apologies for late response. Some how I missed your question. I have added ans. Do let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you ID from FormViewController to ViewController and append id to your album name while creating album. Define id in ViewController as

```
var id : String = ""
```

Pass id from FormViewController to your ViewController as

```
let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController ") as! ViewController 
myVC.id= ID!
navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

Append id to album name before creating new album to save your image as.

```
albumName += id.
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album) link for help saving image to custom album in PHAssest.