# How to save image/video to favorites Album?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I am able to save **Image/Video** to **Camera Roll** in album using method **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum** respectively.

Now I want to add image to **Favorites** in Album, how can I add image/video here?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album) may help you out.

Comment: This is also saving image to Camera Roll using PHPhotoLibrary no in Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using Photos framework. PHAssetChangeRequest has a property isFavorite. You can set true as mentioned in below code: -

Swift 3:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.videoWatermarkedURL!)
    request?.isFavorite = true
}) { saved, error in
    if saved {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            UIAlertController.sharedInstance().showAlert(withTitle: AMTSavezees, message: "Video Saved in Favorite!", autoHideDuration: 3)
        })
    }
}
```

Good luck.